# How to commit a modified file if it wasn't locked by RCS beforehand (and I'm using Emacs VC mode)?

Tags: emacs

Sometimes, a file under the control of RCS gets modified while it is not locked (= checked out for modification by me).

(In these cases, it was actually set read-only by RCS to prevent such modifications; but it might have been a configuration file under /etc/ which was modified because I was upgrading packages.)

And then usually I want to nevertheless commit the new modifications, as if the last revision has been checked out before the modification.

How is it best to proceed then?

I usually use Emacs VC, and do `C-x v v` to check out and in. But if the file hasn't been checked out beforehand, this fails. Is there a way to proceed specifically from within Emacs? But answers with shell commands are also welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually it's much simpler.  You can just do `rcs -l` to lock it, then try check it back in again.

I assume the situation when you asked the question was something like this:

```
$ echo v1 >foo
$ ci -u -t-"Test file." foo
$ chmod u+w foo
$ echo v2 >foo
```

At this point, both `ci` and `co` will fail:

```
$ co -l foo
foo,v  -->  foo
revision 1.1 (locked)
writable foo exists; remove it? [ny](n): 

$ ci -u foo
foo,v  <--  foo
ci: foo,v: no lock set by username
```

This is how you can lock the file and commit the changes:

```
$ rcs -l foo
RCS file: foo,v
1.1 locked
done
$ ci -u -m"Second revision." foo
foo,v  <--  foo
new revision: 1.2; previous revision: 1.1
done
```

Comment: Thanks! You've described the situation precisely. I remembered there was a simple option like this, having found out about it before, but when I ran into this problem this time, I only looked into the manpage for `co`, and didn't read carefully the manpage for `rcs`, that's probably why I couldn't find the `rcs -l` option again.

Answer (score 1):

A special mode of RCS operation, which is mentioned in the Emacs manual (info) in the VC section, could be an option of how to overcome such problems:

> #### 32.1.12.2 Options for RCS and SCCS
>
> By default, RCS uses locking to coordinate the activities of several
>   users, but there is a mode called "non-strict locking" in which you
>   can check-in changes without locking the file first.  Use **`rcs -U` to
>   switch to non-strict locking** for a particular file, see the `rcs`
>   manual page for details.

But, of course, one might not want to switch to the non-strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Unix commands can be used to achieve the goal. So, actually, it's not a big problem at all.

1. copy/move the modified file out the way of RCS (`cp FILE FILE.new`, `mv FILE FILE.new`, or `C-x C-w FILE.new` in Emacs);
2. check out (and lock) the last revision from RCS (`co -l FILE` or in Emacs: `C-x C-f FILE` -- open it again, and `C-x v v`);
3. overwrite it with the new modifications;
4. commit it (`ci ...` or in Emacs: `C-x v v`).

(Besides this basic way, other simpler ways to achieve the goal might be interesting, too, i.e., with a specific option for this case.)